# How to confine HTML selection range to text itself

Tags: html, css, selection

This question has long bothered me from time to time.

When we crate a paragraph/list/span within a div, we expect users to be able to select only the text, instead of the entire horizontal block on the webpage.

But when I create a webpage, what I get when selecting text is below:

[image]

Is there anyway to limit users' range of selection through html or CSS? Or is it the way I structure the divs that causes the problem?

The *ideal* situation:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like only Chrome creates a full-page-width selection like on a pic. 1. Firefox, Opera, and IE 10 deal with it like on a pic. 2. ([Check yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/GdW9p/1/).)

There is a non-standard CSS property which may give the expected result: `user-select: element` (supported by Webkit, Firefox, and IE 10 with respected prefixes);
it restricts selection to the bounds of the selected element. However there is no use of it: Webkit doesn't support `element` value, and other browsers already work like you want.

---

#### Update

Looks like `float: left` or `position: relative` "fix" text selection in Chrome. ([See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GdW9p/2/).)

Comment: Thanks for the information! Is it because of the margin:0 auto attribute? I mean, in other situation (including this website) it seems to work fine for Chrome

Comment: Great insight! Although I have no idea how float or positioning can help defining user selection, it works really well for Chrome. Thanks again.